# RxJava method conversion to RxJava3

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java3

this is a method written in RxJava

```
    public Observable<String> method() {
    return model.getOffers()
            .filter(new Func1<Offers, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Offers offers) {
                    if (offers == null)
                        return false;
                    return offers.hasSuperOffer();
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<Offers, Observable<Long>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Long> call(Offers offers) {
                    Long offerEndTime = offers.getRemainingTime();
                    if (offerEndTime == null) {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                    AtomicLong remainingTimeSec;
                    Long currentTimeSec = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    if (remainingTimeSec.get() == -1 && (offerEndTime > currentTimeSec)) {
                        remainingTimeSec.set(offerEndTime - currentTimeSec);
                    } else {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                    return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .onBackpressureDrop()
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .take(remainingTimeSec.intValue())
                            .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                                @Override
                                public void call() {
                                }
                            })
                            .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                                @Override
                                public void call() {
                                }
                            })
                            .map(new Func1<Long, Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public Long call(Long elapsedTimeSec) {
                                    return remainingTimeSec.getAndDecrement();
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Long remainingTime) {
                    return DateUtils.getRemainingTimeStr(remainingTime);
                }
            });
}
```

I am trying to convert it to RxJava3 but some parameters have changed:
Func1 has been changed to Function
Action0 has been changed to Action

After I'm making the changes the following error appears at filter:

```
filter (io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Predicate <? MyClass> in Observable cannot be applied to (anonymous.io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function <MyClass.model.Offers.java.lang.Boolean>)
```

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: Boolean returning functions have been changed to `io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Predicate`, as the error message indicates.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd ! In case someone needs to know what are the changes I'll leave the code:
`code
.filter(new Predicate<Offers>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Offers offers) {
                        if (offers == null)
                            return false;
                        return offers.hasSuperOffer();
                    }
                })
`